# Quandl stock identifiers

Tags: identifier, bloomberg, financial, quandl

I have a list of 1,000 stock identifiers (Bloomberg ticker, ISIN; SEDOL or CUSIP) and I would like to download data from quandl. However, I cannot map the identifiers.

The problem is that Quandl uses its own Quandl codes which are built as:

Database/ticker

Bloomberg tickers on the other hand have also exchange information which Quandl codes don't have

For example, Wal-Mart Stores has ticker WMT and its Quandl code is WIKI/WMT.

However, this ticker is also valid for WEST MOUNTAIN ENVIRONMENTALb in Bloomberg.

Comment: The ticker (three letter symbol) is not unique. In your case WMT is a valid ticker in the US and in Canada but are not the same stock. Without additional information (such as the exchange) it will be difficult...

Comment: So... what exactly is your question? It sounds like you are going to need to build a map of these identifiers - I doubt any individual data provider is going to provide a map of their tickers to another provider's tickers, so I would expect you to have to do it yourself.

Comment: Yes, it looks as if a lot of manual work would be necessary here...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ISIN and map the Tickers.

for example to use the indian fundamental data you have to got to

https://www.quandl.com/data/DEB-Core-India-Fundamentals-Data/documentation

documentation > coverage & data organisation > tickers

Under that you can see

"The list of companies available in this data feed, including their names and IDs as listed on the BSE and NSE, can be downloaded here."

click the "here" and download the ticker and its ISIN map.

Answer (score -1):

Quandl does not have any normalized identifier system, each data provider determines their own key.  The WIKI data source you reference has data for ~3000 US companies and it is their convention that WMT is Walmart.  Since they only cover the US, there is no confusion and the base ticker works just fine.

For each of your tickers, you will need to determine if there is a datasource providing data for that company and identify the appropriate identifier in that dataset.  There is no guarantee that every ticker you wish to work with even has data on Quandl